# Countdown Timer in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am displaying a countdown timer in _Layout.cshtml page using this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/hHD4w/28/).

But when I move from one page to another page, the timer is starting again when the new page loads.
1.How to display the timer without starting again when it navigates to a new page.
2.How to stop the user refreshing the page so that the timer doesnt start again.

My Layout code :

```
     <table width="100%">
   <tr>
   <td width="2%">
   <img src="~/Images/philips_new.png" alt="" height="45" width="155" />
   </td>
   <td width="79%" align="right" class="Text_nocolor">
   <span class="Text_nocolor">
  @{ Html.RenderAction("GetUserName", "Login");}
   </span>
  </td>
  <td width="4%">
<div id="counter">
 </div>
 </td>
 <td width="4%" class="Text_nocolor" valign="middle">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Login", new { controller = "Login" })">
 <img src="~/Images/nome-logout.png" alt="" height="24" width="30" style="border-style: none; cursor: pointer;" /></a>
  </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

I tried using the jquery plugin countdown timer , but it shows object doesnt support this property error in IE.
Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: what you mean by Stop refreshing ?

Comment: when the user refreshes the page, the timer starts from the beginning again.

Comment: that will happen. You can store the value in a cookie and read from cookie.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.How to display the timer without starting again when it navigates to a new page.    You can store the counter value in a cookie. This is

the easy way , you can pass the value between pages.

> 2.How to stop the user refreshing the page so that the timer doesnt start again.

If you are using a cookie to store the value, I think this can be solved. I don't know what you meants by this issue.

What is your exact aim ?

Comment: Is there any other way without using cookies? Because if the browser has cookies disabled then this functionality will not work

Comment: Yes Sure.. Let me check again and reply to u

Comment: see if you can use the `localStorage`

Answer (score 0):

use an ajax function to call an action which will store the timer value in session. Thus even if the user refreshes the page, you still have the current value.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can Use the javascript time which is sync with the server side code on each postback or page refresh.

Use the following code

```
 var dt = '@ViewBag.EndDate';
var dateAr = dt.split('-');
var newDate = dateAr[1] + '/' + dateAr[0] + '/' + dateAr[2];

var end = new Date(dateAr[1] + '/' + dateAr[0] + '/' + dateAr[2]);

var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
var _hour = _minute * 60;
var _day = _hour * 24;
var timer;

function showRemaining() {
   var now = new Date();
   var distance = end - now;
   if (distance &lt; 0) {
       clearInterval(timer);
       document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';
       window.location.href = '/Home/Index';

       return;
   }
var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);


document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = hours + 'hrs ';
document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';
```

}

```
timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
```

You can Follow this link

http://www.csharptrick.com/2014/09/count-timer-asp-net-mvc-exams/

Comment: dead link above